# The Integrality theorem in maximum flow

Tags: bipartite, network-flow

The integraloty theorem tells us that if all capacities in a flow network are integers, then there is **a** maximum flow where every value is an integer

But the most remarkable part is the existence, not every maximum flow!
Which means this statement doesn't claim ***every*** maximum flow is integer-valued

I cannot figure out why if all capacities are integer, but there exists a maximum flow is not integer-valued!!

Or did I just get wrong idea of this theorem that tries to tell me?

Answer (score 10):

Let

- e = edge in the graph.
- c(e) = capacity of the given edge e
- f(e) = amount of flow going through given edge e

The theorem states:

> If c(e) for all edges, e, in graph are integers, then there exists a max flow
>   f for which every flow value f(e) is an integer.

Notice the theorem **does not place constraint** on **f(e)**.

Only **c(e)** must be integer.
Since **"c(e) must be integer" does not imply "f(e) must be integer"** as well.
Therefore it is perfectly valid to have non-integer flow with integer capacity.

Here is an example where all capacities are integer with a maximum flow that has some edges that has non-integer flow..

G is the flow Graph I am working with..
N is a maximum integral flow..
N` is a maximum flow where it has some edges has non-integer flow..

pair number on edges are of format: "flow/capacity"

[image: Graph that shows an example flow graph and two maximum flows which I am gonna use:]

Remember the theorem only says the upper bound of f(u,v) are integers.. it does not say anything about its lower bound.. therefore flow can be any number between 0 and c(u,v)..

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10313918)

Comment: @eirenaios Picture added. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: looks great! Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

If using Ford-Fulkerson method to get a maximum flow, then the resulted flow must be integer-valued

But, we still can have a maximum flow that use real number as the flow value on the edges

Check this example:

```
          B
        /   \
       /     \
      /       \
```

s------A　　　　　　t

```
      \       /
       \     /
        \   /
          C
```

the directions of edges all go from left to right , and the (s,a) has 1 flow and 1 capacity,

and rest of all all go with 0.5 flow and 1 capacity.

This is flow network having a maximum flow but not integer-valued.